# why {key:'value'} is printing "value" in console

Tags: javascript, console

While I was testing saw a behavior of console(Chrome). if i type `console.log({key:'value'})` is printing  `Object {key: "value"}` which was expected by me. But when I directly typed `{key:'value'}` in console it printing `'value'` only while I expected `Object {key: "value"}`.

Saw same behavior in IE10 and FF.
What is the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your object is instead being interpreted as a block statement with a single statement within consisting of a string literal preceded by a label.

```
//  v---block----v
    {key: "value"}
//    ^--label
```

For the console to interpret it as object literal syntax, it needs to be part of an expression. If you wrap in parens, you'll get the expected result.

```
({key:"value"})
```

---

*Side note:*

Here's the really weird part. A statement is a statement because it doesn't *return* anything. So why does it return `"value"`?

In JavaScript, statements have something like a final value. *(I don't remember exactly what it's called.)* It isn't anything that's useful or reachable in program code, but when a program is evaluated, that final value will be returned to whatever evaluated it.

The same goes when you use `eval()` to evaluate a program. Its final statement value will be returned. Since code in a console is `eval`'d, it gets that final value and prints it.

Comment: I think you are right it is being interpreted as JavaScript Label.

Comment: @Shusl: Yeah, it's very similar to the issue where you try to `return` an object literal. If you have this: `return {foo: "bar"};`, but instead of having the `{` on the same line as the `return`, you have it on the next line, the interpreter puts a `;` after the `return` because it sees the `{foo:"bar"}` as a separate block statement.

Answer (score 1):

That's because what you type is interpreted.

`{key:'value'}` is a block and returns "value". You'd have had the same result with just `key:'value'` or `'value'`.

If you want an expression returning your object, type `({key:'value'})`.